# New Relic notice error not showing up after exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, newrelic, error-logging

We're using New Relic to log and monitor errors in our Java application.

We have set up a Spring Controller Advice, and in some cases we need to use the Notice Error functionality in the agent.

This works fine when it's used at any other place, but it doesn't show up in New Relic when it's used after an exception has been thrown (and caught by the controller advice.)

Does the agent ignore any errors after an exception? Is there a way to use Notice Error from a controller advice?

Comment: Also, an error doesn't show up even if it's noticed before the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

After submitting a ticket to New Relic and running some tests, we found a solution. 
Setting the following in your configuration will solve the problem.

```
error_collector:
ignoreErrorPriority: false
```

Otherwise, exceptions will always take priority over notices.